# Select particular line in paragraph w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to select a specific line in a text paragraph with jQuery? I do not have any specific text in mind, so I don't know if REGEX would help, but let's say I have a text that wraps into 5 lines, can I add a class, for example to line number 3?

I've seen fancier things done with jQuery, and do hope there's power to do this, just don't know how.

Comment: What separates these "lines".  jQuery has an addClass method you could employ to add the class to the line once you've gotten it.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless each line is constructed with a separate element. Calculating line breaks in text is a really, really tough task since different font styles and attributes are involved. You will need to write an algorithm (or use an existing one) that calculates where text wraps given font attributes and dimensions of the container. Regex won't help you here either.