# JQuery - Is it possible to add css to all lines of text that start the same within an element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, target, lines

I have a Div that contains a lot of lines of text. Some of this is just meta information about the text above it, and these lines always begin `##` followed by a space. Unfortunately this content is pulled in from a database so I'm unable to style at source.

Is it possible to target these lines with a for each loop or an alternative method and use the `.css()` or `.addClass()` to style with css?

Here's an example div

```
    <div class="lotsOfLines">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            ## Created 28112016 2006 - Ste
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
            Adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            ## Edited 28112016 2021 - Ste
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            ## Updated 28112016 2308 - Ste
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            ## Updated 28112016 2335 - Ste
    </div>
```

Searched but closest information i found was [Select particular line in paragraph w/ jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318723/select-particular-line-in-paragraph-w-jquery) which doesn't lead to much information.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually that answer you linked gives a lot of information. It is very difficult to target text without a node. But, if you were very determined, you could theoretically use a regex this time because you know the beginning of the sentence, so match every ## to the new line at the end of the sentence. I am not 100% with regex but you can try here http://regexr.com/. Then you can use the jQuery .wrap() method to wrap a paragraph node around it and style that. But in all honesty, what are you using to connect to the database as you can always add nodes to the fetch statements.